# i am not able to initiialise data members of different classes in multiple inheritance in python2.X

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, method-resolution-order

I have a code that goes like this

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        super(a, self).__init__()

    def displayA(self):
        print self.x
        print self.y

class b(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        super(b, self).__init__()

    def displayB(self):
        print self.name


class c(a,b):
    def __init__(self, p,x,y,name):
        self.p = p
        b.name=name     #**this line confuses me**
        super(c,self).__init__(x,y)

    def displayC(self):
        print self.p

v = c(10, 12, 78, 'abc')
v.displayC()
v.displayA()
v.displayB()
```

I want to initialise the data members of different classes (a & b) through the subclass c, but the super() visits only class a, but somehow I can initialise class b data members like `b.name=name` in the **init**() of c and then I can pass the parameters in the object. 
My question is, if I dont do it like this, I cannot pass arguments in the c's object.
Help me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
    a.__init__(self,x,y)
    b.__init__(self,name)
```

### Edit:

OK, missed question about `b.name`. Remove that line. In this context b is class. `b.__init__` is special convention to show which parent constructor you are willing to call.

And that is not duplicate. Hope, now it helps.

### Edit2:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        print("a " + str(x) + " - " + str(y) )

    def displayA(self):
        print self.x
        print self.y

class b(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        print("b " + name )

    def displayB(self):
        print self.name


class c(a,b):
    def __init__(self, p,x,y,name):
        self.p = p
        a.__init__(self,x,y)
        b.__init__(self,name)

    def displayC(self):
        print self.p

v = c(10, 12, 78, 'abc')
v.displayC()
v.displayA()
v.displayB()
```

Result:

```
a 12 - 78
b abc
10
12
78
abc
```

Can you edit, your initial post, and show me what is the problem? For me that is the answer, and that was from starting point...

Comment: can you tell me why b.name = name works? i am confused by this

Comment: but Is'nt ClassName__init__(), is an old method of calling constructors? i have heard a term called "co-operative subclassing" in which we have to declare superclass in each class, but my question is still intact ! i cannot initiate class b's constructor by c class object

Comment: all I wanted was to initialise the superclass constructors (class a & b) from the subclass contructor (class c) with the help of super(), but all i could find is, it only initialised the first class contructor (i.e class a) not the second class (class b). what you are doing is totally fine and i can understand the code you've written. I want to ask is, is initialising like the way you did is still in practice (i have read somewhere that it is an older method to do)? or there is any other way of doing the same thing with super()? @Michal Zaborowski

Comment: `super()` gives more flexibility, since you are not instrumenting it all manually. However here there are different set of parameters, and it would not work...

Comment: what you are saying is, the only way to do it is, doing the way you did?

Comment: other option is to skip constructor(s) of parent's class(es) and copy that code to `c.__init__`. That is object with fields, so if you use `self.name` instead of `b.name` - should work as well.